# Indoor Atlas SDK IALocationManager in background

Tags: android, service, sdk, positioning, tracking

Service that performs background operations to provide positioning updates to IALocationManager component. Do not invoke this service directly but use IALocationManager instead.

This method is called by **startServcie(mIntent)**:

```
public class IndooTrackingService extends IALocationService implements 
IALocationListener {

private IALocationManager mLocationManager;
mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(IALocationRequest.create(), this);
mLocationManager = IALocationManager.create(this);
...

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(IALocation iaLocation) {
    Log.i(tag, "IALocationChange: " + iaLocation);
    final LocationEvent event = new LocationEvent(mMyLocationSource, 
    iaLocation);
    mLocationChannel.publish(mFloorPlanIdLocal, event);
}

}
```

This is the logcat:

```
Caught a RuntimeException from the binder stub implementation.                                                      
android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling: 
com.indooratlas.android.sdk.IALocation
...
Class not found when unmarshalling:
com.indooratlas.android.sdk.IALocation                                                         
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.indooratlas.android.sdk.IALocation
```

Comment: Are you using the emulator or a physical device to test with?

Comment: Im using a physical device @CliveSeebregts